# Add page to QStackedWidget at Design time Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtgui, qstackedwidget

I currently need 3 pages in my QStackedWidget. However, in Qt Designer I am only allowed to add 2 pages. After I click the next arrow on QStackedWidget, it takes me back to the previous page instead of taking me to a new page.

How can I add a new page to QStackedWidget in Qt Designer?

Comment: While there is already an answer, I just want to say that the arrow buttons are for switching between different stacked pages so that you can edit it freely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right Click -> Insert Page -> Before/After Current Page

[image]